# Preventing from cheating

Tags: html, cookies, ip

I'm currently making a facemash analog and I found out that it's very easy to cheat ^^ If you type this in your browser several times: http://domain.com/rate.php?winner=1&loser=2, you can make photo №1 a winner. I know that it's possible to prevent it with cookies and ip-blocking, but I don't know how exactly. Please help me. Thanks!

Thant's an example (not mine):
http://facemash.moefelt.dk/

UPD I can provide a source code if needed.

UPD 1 rate.php http://jsfiddle.net/6xLR6/
      index.php http://jsfiddle.net/AvF4M/1/

Comment: cookies aren't secure it can be tampered, ip blocking also makes less sense coz different computers under a network may only have the same ip address, I THINK CAPTCHA makes more sense

Comment: if you find it annoying then use $_POST  and $_SESSION at least cheat will be harder

Comment: @jerjer cl.ly/41391F3U2I2N0Y3P0R2A I just replace $_GET with $_POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply use $_POST instread of $_GET, the cheat would be harder !

cookies can be saved in cache but if the user clean it everytime, it could be useless.

**EDIT :**

```
<form METHOD=POST ACTION="rate.php">

<table>
<tr>
        <td><img src="images/<?=$images[0]->filename?>" /></td>
        <td><img src="images/<?=$images[1]->filename?>" /></td>

<input type="radio" name="winer" value="First"> First<br>
<input type="radio" name="winer" value="Second"> Second

<input type="hidden"  name="first"  value="<?=$images[0]->image_id?>">
<input type="hidden"  name="second"  value="<?=$images[1]->image_id?>">
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

In rate.php :

```
<?php 
$winerId = $_POST['winer'];

if ($_POST['winer'] == $_POST['first']){
$looser = $_POST['second'];}
else { $looser = $_POST['second']; }
...
```

I think that you got all that you want right now ;-)

Comment: yes, and on the page that calls that page, put FORM Method="POST" instead of FORM Method="GET" ;-)

Comment: That didn't solve the problem. And there's no FORM Method="GET" on my index.php page: http://jsfiddle.net/AvF4M/

Comment: please paste the index.php in the first post (edit it) and giv me the code before your table !

Comment: You're coding that site very dirty. You put all your url on absolute. You must encode all with the submission of a form. I put an exempla asap in my forst ask

Comment: post = infos in the header, get = infos in the url. http://www.tizag.com/phpT/postget.php

Comment: I don't understand two lines with type="hidden"... What is that for?

Comment: @Pavel : you have to use the id of the two pictures in the treatment page (rate.php). If you delete those two lines, you will just receive the $_POST['winer'];. Thanks to those hidden inputs, you will also get $_POST['first']; and $_POST['second']; that represents the id of the two pictures ;-) (first ask again edited)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6687/discussion-between-pavel-shimansky-and-clement)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use query parameters. User POST request to send data to server.

Comment: cl.ly/41391F3U2I2N0Y3P0R2A I just replace $_GET with $_POST?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['face']))
    {
        //add another session verifier, at least you can prevent multiple votes in 1 browser session
        if(!isset($_SESSION['done']))
        {
            $face = trim($_POST['pace']);
            //store $face votes to db
            $_SESSION['done'] = true;
        }
    }
?>


<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="face" value="1" />
    <input type="image" src="image1.gif" />
</form>

<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="face" value="2" />
    <input type="image" src="image2.gif" />
</form>
```

Comment: he had to have the id of the two pictures when he submit something ;-)

Answer (score 1):

First question is what is the attack you want to prevent? If it's simply to make sure someone loads the page before submitting an answer, you'll need to:

- Generate a unique token in the page which is part of the submission form (hidden)
- On submission, check that the token is valid and hasn't been previously used

However, this doesn't stop someone writing a bot to vote lots of times.

If you want to make sure that a genuine human has clicked on each load, you'll need to do the above and also include a captcha to verify that the person clicking is human.